# Automating Selendroid and Selenium Tests through maven

Tags: maven, selenium, android-testing

Is it possible to automate Selendroid Tests for Android as well as Selenium for Web Browsers(together) through maven? Do i need to create seperate pom files for both or is it possible to use a single pom file to run both type of Tests?
Can i use any other framework to test Android and WebApps together through maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single pom file. Just configure plugins for each test type you want to use.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting a error in my pom but solved it.

Comment: @LoneChaos I'm looking for the configuration, can you please share it with me ?